# RapidMiner append to file

Tags: csv, append, rapidminer, writetofile

When I have multiple write to CSV processes and they all append to the same file, how do I arrange the order?  Also, does the append lead to the new text added to the beginning of the file or the end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can see what order your operators will be executed in by going to:**

Process->Operator Execution Order->Show Execution Order

**You can reorder them by going to:**

Process->Operator Execution Order->? Order Execution

The appended text will be added to the end of the file.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but will mark it as correct for now.  Thank you so much!